# Yii2 проблема с выводом GridView

Tags: yii2, gridview, link

Есть 2 таблицы - Driver и Company, связанные между собой. В модели Driver такая связь:

```
public function getCompany()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Company::className(), ['id' => 'company_id']);
}
```

Мне нужно во вьюхе Driver вывести информацию о водителе. Ячейка "company" должна быть ссылкой на полную информацию о данной компании из модели Company.
Но когда я прописываю это в columns:

```
[
          'attribute' => 'company',
          'format' => 'raw',
          'value' => function($company_model){
           return Html::a($company_model->name, Url::to(['/company/view','id' => $company_model->id], true), ['data-toggle'=>'modal', 'data-target' => '.test']);
    },
    ],
```

то вместо отображения "Company 1", появляется имя водителя.
[image: problem]
Помогите решить плз.
Вот весь код из GridView:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            // 'id',
            [
                'attribute' => 'name',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function($model){
                    return Html::a($model->name, Url::to(['/driver/view','id' => $model->id], true), ['data-toggle'=>'modal', 'data-target' => '.bs-example-modal-lg']);
                },
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'company',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function($company_model){
                    return Html::a($company_model->name, Url::to(['/company/view','id' => $company_model->id], true), ['data-toggle'=>'modal', 'data-target' => '.test']);
                },
                ],
            'tel_number',
            'city',
            'email:email',
            'dob',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Вот код actionIndex из контроллера:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new DriverSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $model =  Driver::find()->all();
        $company_model = Company::find()->select('name')->all();

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' => $model,
            'company_model' => $company_model,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
[
   {
      'attribute' => 'company',
      'format' => 'raw',
      'value' => function($driver){
       return Html::a($driver->company->name, Url::to(['/company/view','id' => $driver->company_id], true), ['data-toggle'=>'modal', 'data-target' => '.test']);
   },
],
```

Comment: Тогда вообще ничего не отображается. Просто пустая строка.

Comment: 'value' => function($model){
                    return Html::a($model->company->name, Url::to(['/company/view','id' => $model->company->id], true), ['data-toggle'=>'modal', 'data-target' => '.test']);
                },
Так тоже ничего не выходит

Comment: Данные точно там есть? Проверьте в контроллере так: $driver = Driver::findOne($id); echo 'company name =' . $driver->company->name; die; где $id - тот первый id из грида.

Еще, чтобы загрузить данные жадно, надо добавить $query->with('company') к DriverSearch.search()

Comment: echo 'company name =' . $driver->company->name; die; тоже вывел пустоту. Хотя я проверял, можно ли вытащить данные из базы во вьюху вот так, и оно выдавало то, что нужно:

Comment: $data = ArrayHelper::toArray($company_model);
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $test[] = $item['name'];
        }
        foreach($test as $item){
            $name = $item;
            echo $name;
        }

Comment: По прежнему не работает, перепробовал кучу вариантов уже. Ничего так и не помогло...(

Comment: @Neko, если echo 'company name =' . $driver->company->name; die; тоже вывел пустоту тогда скорее всего у вас нет данных в БД

Comment: @Ali Пожалуйста, внесите все обновления в тело ответа!

Comment: Данные в БД есть. Проверял через phpMyAdmin. Потом еще через массив вручную выводил - работает

Answer (score 0):

Так и не получилось что-то сделать с GridView. Реализовал с помощью ListView, но возникла проблема. Не нашёл в ListView такую же полосу поиска, как в GridView. Кто знает, как добавить ее?